# Workflow not creating new site

Tags: workflow, site-template, sub-site, project-templates

I currently have a workflow that creates new subsites for each project when it is added to the project list. I updated the template used, went into the workflow and edited the variable for the template (replaced both the id number and the name). I went to test it, and now the workflow is NOT creating a new subsite, however, it is going through the entire workflow and saying it is completed.

I verified the app permissions as well, and this did not have any effect.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your workflow logic?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I figured it out. I changed the File name after I created it and did not realize I still had to use the original file name when declaring it in the workflow.